# Error in Matlab function block in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I aks question here about my time error I've experienced and someone answer me. the code goes like this

```
function y = IsBetween5AMand7PM
coder.extrinsic('clock');
time = clock;
current = 3600*time(4) + 60*time(5) + time(6); %seconds passed from the beginning of day until now
morning = 3600*7; %seconds passed from the beginning of day until 7AM
evening = 3600*17; %seconds passed from the beginning of day until 5PM
y = current > morning && current < evening; 
end
```

I tried putting this on simulink with a matlab function block and connected it to display but errors like this occured

```
  Subscripting into an mxArray is not supported.
   Function 'MATLAB Function2' (#49.99.106), line 4, column 20: "time(4)"

 Undefined function or variable 'current'. The first assignment to a local variable determines its class.
 Function 'MATLAB Function2' (#49.340.347), line 7, column 9: "current"

 Undefined function or variable 'current'. The first assignment to a local variable determines its class.
 Function 'MATLAB Function2' (#49.361.368), line 7, column 30:"current"

 Errors occurred during parsing of MATLAB function 'MATLAB Function2'
```

The main fuction of this block is to identify whether time is between 7AM-5PM to have an output. Please help.

Comment: @brainkz this is the error I am talking about please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At compile time, Simulink needs to be able to determine the size and datatype of the variables.  In your case, it needs to know about `time`.

To enable your code to work, insert

```
time = zeros(1,6);
```

immediately before the `time = clock` line.

Comment: Oh ok.. im going to try that... Thank you

Comment: there still is an error.. It says undefined variable for zero

Comment: hey it finally works!! Thank you so much for ther help 